# Fast EELS acquisation

Tags: hardware, dm-script

To acquire EELS, I used these below,

```
img:=camera.cm_acquire(procType,exp,binX, binY,tp,lf,bt,rt)
imgSP:=img.verticalSum() //this is a custom function to do vertical sum
```

and this,

```
imgSP:=EELSAcquireSpectrum(exp, nFrames, binX, binY, processing)
```

When using either one in my customized 2D mapping, they are much slower than the "spectrum Imaging" from Gatan. (The first one is faster than the 2nd one). Is the lack of speed the natural limitation with scripting? or there are better function calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lack of speed is a limitation of the scripting giving you only access to the camera in single read mode. I.e. one command initiates the camera, exposes it, reads it out and returns the image.

In SpectrumImaging the camera is run in continuous mode, i.e. the same as if you have the live view running. The cameras is constantly exposed and reads out (with shutter, depending on the type of camera). This mode of camera acquisition is available as camera script command from GMS 3.4.0 onward.